# Subset of Pandas MultiIndex works for whole index but not for specific level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I've run into strange behaviour with a `pd.MultiIndex` and am trying to understand what's going on. Not looking for a solution so much as an explanation.

Suppose I have a MultiIndexed dataframe:

```
index0 = pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], name='let')
index1 = pd.Index(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], name='word')
x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], index=[index0, index1])

display(x)

        0   1   2
let word            
a   foo 1   2   3
b   bar 4   5   6
c   baz 7   8   9
```

If I then take a subset of that dataframe with `df.loc`:

```
sub = ['a', 'c']
y = x.loc[sub]
display(y)

        0   1   2
let word            
a   foo 1   2   3
c   baz 7   8   9
```

So far, so good. Now, looking at the index of the new dataframe:

```
display(y.index)

MultiIndex([('a', 'foo'),
            ('c', 'baz')],
           names=['let', 'word'])
```

That makes sense too. But if I look at a specific level of the subset dataframe's index...

```
display(y.index.levels[1])

Index(['bar', 'baz', 'foo'], dtype='object', name='word')
```

Suddenly I have the values of the original full dataframe, not the selected subset!

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

We need to add a specific function `remove_unused_levels` to this , since it is category type data

```
y.index.levels[0]
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='let')

# after add
y.index=y.index.remove_unused_levels()
y.index.levels[0]
Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object', name='let')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `levels` and `get_level_values`:

```
y.index.get_level_values(1)
# Index(['foo', 'baz'], dtype='object', name='word')
```

`y.index.levels` is as Ben mentioned in his answer, just all possible values (before truncated). Let's see another example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0]], 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[0,1,2]]))
```

So `df` would look like:

```
     0
0 0  0
  1  0
  2  0
1 0  0
  1  0
  2  0
```

Now what do you think we would get with `df.index.levels[1]`? The answer is:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

which consists of all the possible values in the level. Whereas, `df.index.get_level_values(1)` gives:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```